# Asp.net core & Identity server: External logins not working

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I've set up an asp.net core (2.1) application using asp.net identity and plugged in Identity Server 4 as the auth middleware. This is working well for local accounts, but now I'm trying to enable 3rd party login providers, starting with Google.
So I added the following to my ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ClientId = "numbershere.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "my-secret";
                });
```

And added the UI scaffolding in to the project and my Google Sign In button appears. If I click it, I get redirected to Google, log in and get presented with the confirmation screen before being returned to my app.
At this point, `OnGetCallbackAsync` of my `ExternalLoginModel` is being hit, which contains a call:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

However, info is always null after this call and the user is therefore just redirected back to the login page:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
}
```

I've read about online and even followed the points in the [Identity Server quick start](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html), but can't see what I've missed.

Can anyone advise what I've not done/configured to make this work?

Thanks